# Java экземпляры класса

Tags: java, объекты

Всем привет! Помогите понять простой пример:

```
public class Test16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Qwe q1 = new Qwe();
        Qwe q2 = q1;
        q1.q = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            q2.q = q2.q + q1.q;
            System.out.println(q2.q);
            System.out.println(q1.q);
        }


    }
    public static class Qwe {
        int q = 0;
    }
}

Вывод будет такой:
2  
2       //Вопрос, почему увеличивается переменная q экземпляра класса q1, когда она должна быть всегда = 1? 
4
4
```

Видимо я не понимаю вот эту строчку `Qwe q2 = q1;` Что здесь происходит?
Если вместо неё написать `Qwe q2 = new Qwe();` тогда вывод будет:

```
1
1    // это понятно
2
1
```

Comment: `Qwe q2 = q1;` - Вы объявляете переменную `q2`, которая ссылается на   тот же объект, что и `q1`.

Comment: Это понимаю, но почему  q1.q изменяется в цикле ?

Comment: Дошло наконец! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Qwe q2 = q1;` Здесь вы присваиваете q2 ссылку на класс q1. 
Вывод абсолютно правильный и в одном в другом случае. 
В первом он правильный так как в q2 у нас ссылка на q1, а это значит, что все значения переменных так же передались в q2. 
в цикле у вас q2 равно `1`, а после этого вы к добавляете к этому значению 0 = 1 + 1;

Если присвоить `Qwe q2 = new Qwe();` тогда значения q будет равно не одному, а 0. И по этому другой вывод.

Когда вы передаете ссылку на класс в другой класс `Qwe q2 = q1;` вы так же передаете все значения переменных это классу, а так как q1.q  была присвоена `1`, в q2, переменная q так же равно одному.

Comment: Всё равно не доходит, давайте я напишу как думаю, а Вы меня поправите :)
q1.q = 1
Итерация 1:
q2.q = 1 (так как q2 ссылается на q1) + 1 = 2 
но q1.q = должен быть равен 1, почему он стал 2? 

Итерация 2: 
q2. q = 2 + 1 = 3 Опять же, если бы до меня дошло почему меняется q1.q тогда и q2.q будет понятно.

Отсюда и вопрос почему q1.q меняется? )) Понимаю, что простое не понимаю.  

Хотя в теории всё понятно.

Comment: @Игорь так как два класса ссылаются на одну область в пам"яти и если в классе q2 параметр q изменился, значит он так же изменится в классе q1 без очного этому присваивания.

Comment: @Игорь q2 и q1 это один и тот же объект. Меняете q2 - меняется q1.

Comment: Спасибо!! Теперь понял!